# Cloud 9 ruby on rails error while making articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am getting an error that says:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mw12.png (this is the image  of the error)

new.html.erb

```
<h1>  Create an article  </h1>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%=f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController    

def new
@article = Article.new  

end

end
```

this is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest 
priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# root 'welcome#index'
root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
resources :articles
```

I don't know how to make the article model and if I did I wouldn't know what to put in there... show I would appreciate it if you showed me how [enter image description here][1]

Comment: `class Article < ApplicationRecord; end`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not created Article model in models folder. Therefore it is not able to create a new object. 
Create this a file in your models folder:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

end
```

and then try to create .new command on Article

```
Article.new
```

Comment: so do i have to make an articles.rb file in my models folder?

Comment: I tried what I have understood by the answer you put :                                                                                             
    class Article < ApplicationRecord
    Article.new
    end

Comment: yes, but model name are always singular and controller names are always plural, in your case model name is `article.rb` and controller name is `articles_controller`.

Comment: follow this rails guide for more details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: i am trying to make articles from ui